# GO Lang markdown app

Tags: go, markdown

I have a very simple markdown app in go which works great but I am really struggling to sort the order of the index posts on the page and would like a neat way in the file to do this. Any help appreciated.

html is

```
<section>
{{range .}}
<a href="/{{.File}}"><h2 class="h2_home">{{.Title}} ({{.Date}})</h2></a>
<p>{{.Summary}}</p>
{{end}}
 </section>
```

and the go stuff for the index page is as follows

```
func getPosts() []Post {
a := []Post{}
files, _ := filepath.Glob("posts/*")
for _, f := range files {
    file := strings.Replace(f, "posts/", "", -1)
    file = strings.Replace(file, ".md", "", -1)
    fileread, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(f)
    lines := strings.Split(string(fileread), "\n")
    title := string(lines[0])
    date := string(lines[1])
    summary := string(lines[2])
    body := strings.Join(lines[3:len(lines)], "\n")
    htmlBody := template.HTML(blackfriday.MarkdownCommon([]byte(body)))

    a = append(a, Post{title, date, summary, htmlBody, file, nil})
}
return a
}
```

Ive not looked at it for a while as it just works but I really want to put something into the file to support ordering. The .md file is formatted

```
Hello Go lang markdown blog generator!
12th Jan 2015
This is a basic start to my own hosted go lang  markdown static blog/ web generator.
### Here I am...

This entry is a no whistles Hello ... etc
```

Answer (score -2):

See sort.Slice in the sort package. Here is an [example](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#example_Slice) of usage.

For your particular problem, you have a slice a []Post, so just call sort.Slice on it like this:

```
sort.Slice(a, func(i, j int) bool { return a[i].title < a[j].title })
```

This is just sorting all members of the slice a based on their title (assuming you can access this private field of a Post in this package, if not you'd need to add a function).

If you do that your slice a of posts will be sorted by title (or any other criteria you wish, perhaps you could give the user a choice of title or date?). You don't need to adjust your markdown files.

If you want to sort on dates obviously your Post should parse the dates with the time package first so that you have real dates, not just a string.

So something like this (assuming time.Time on the Post):

```
// parse dates
date,err := time.Parse("2nd Jan 2006",string(lines[1]))
if err != nil {
 // deal with it
}   

// later, sort the slice 
sort.Slice(a, func(i, j int) bool { return a[i].date.Before(a[j].date)})
```

Comment: This doesn’t give me much guidance I need to select the line in the markdown that is the date (it is formatted as plain text) and then sort.Slice on that ? How exactly is that to be approached ?

Comment: Edited to add some more detail. Read both sort and time pkg docs and it should be straightforward.

Comment: Thank you will have another attempt